# How can I implement a fill na with avg using rolling window of 7 days in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I have a pyspark df as follow:

[image: 1]

How can I use fill na to fill with average values in a 7 days rolling window, but corresponding to the category value, for instance, desktop to desktop, mobile to mobile, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `coalesce` with the 7-day rolling average:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'sessoes',
    F.coalesce(
        F.col('sessoes'),
        F.avg('sessoes').over(Window.partitionBy('device').orderBy('data').rowsBetween(-7,0))
    )
)
```